# Is sign magnitude used to represent negative numbers?

Tags: c, networking, binary, decimal, cpu-architecture

I understand that the two's complement is used to represent a negative number but there is also the method of using sign magnitude. Is sign magnitude still used to represent negative numbers? If not where was it previously used then? And how is a machine that interprets negative numbers using two's complement able to communicate and understand another machine that uses the sign magnitude instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, sign magnitude is frequently used today, though not where you might expect. For example, [IEEE floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) uses a single "sign" bit to denote positive or negative. (As a result, IEEE floating point numbers can be -0.) Sign magnitude is not commonly used today for integers, however.

Communication between two machines using different number representations only presents a problem if they *both* try to use their native encoding format. If a common format is defined for exchanging information, there is no problem. For example, a machine that uses two's complement can easily construct a number using sign magnitude encoding (and vice versa). These days, different machines are more likely to communicate using the ASCII representation of the number (eg. in JSON or XML), or to use a completely different binary encoding (eg. ASN.1, [zigzag encoding](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#types), etc).

Comment: Note: As a matter of interchange format, ASCII representation like "1.23", "-4.5e6" is also a _sign magnitude_.

Comment: It used to be common to find packed BCD, which was sign-magnitude (although the sign used up a whole nibble). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal#Packed_BCD

Comment: The good old days where BCD-packed integers sometimes didn't start on a byte boundary